# Include hashtag symbol # (twitter) in Beamer footline

Tags: beamer, header-footer, symbols

I need to include the symbol # following by the twitter trending name of the conference. Do you know how to include this special symbol in the preamble before defining mathematical symbols? Thanks!

Comment: welcome to tex.sx.  it's unclear how you want to include this symbol in the preamble; it's not possible to actually typeset anything within the preamble.  please supply an example, preferably a complete short document that can be copied and compiled.

Comment: Thanks! I know. How can I manage the to include my text in the footline including the hash character?

Comment: how is the footline entered?  what is the command you use to specify the footline content?  what document class are you using?  (by the way, `\#` is a native tex command; it does not require math.)

Comment: \setbeamertemplate{footline} {
\hbox{%
\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=1.95\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{myfootlinetext}
    \small{\textbf{\#mytext}}
\end{beamercolorbox}
}
}

Comment: this is much better edited into your question than posted in a comment.  for one thing, the proper line breaks will be shown.

Comment: @Y.Larriba Using your footline with `\#` in the preamble works just fine. Can you make a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows your problem?

Comment: Thanks! It works. I just had to add \text{mytext} after \#, instead of \#mytext

Answer (score 1):

The hash symbol can usually be written with the command `\#` in LaTeX. It is already defined in the LaTeX kernel.

Comment: Thanks! i've tried, it works after \begin{document} but not before it

Comment: The preamble is for loading the class and packages, or making definitions. Typesetting starts after `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 0):

works fine:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{footline} { \hbox{ \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=1.95\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{myfootlinetext} \small{\textbf{\# mytext}} \end{beamercolorbox} } }

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```